# Why was particular comment deleted

Tags: discussion, comments

[This Jon Skeets answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6841479/1149736) had the first comment from Gareth saying something like:

> Please tell me you didn't know that from the top of your head.

As far as I remember it had about 700 upvotes or something like that.

I understand that it's not good or desired comment now, but I think it should have been kept for its historical significance.

Was it deleted by moderator or OP? Why?

Comment: What does it add to the answer?

Comment: Comments are always temporarily, no matter how good, cool or funny they are.

Comment: What is the *historical significance* of that comment? I fail to see any.

Comment: And it probably fell victim to flags. Otherwise subsequent comments would also have been removed, I would assume.

Comment: You realise that comment was deleted on Jul 28 **'14** at 21:03, right?

Answer (score 13):

The comment was deleted by a moderator, **over a year ago**; the deletion timestamp is 2014-07-28 21:03:43Z.

It was deleted as *too chatty*, and that was the 6th flag already on the comment. And indeed, the comment does not meet our [comment guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment):

> #### When should I comment?
>
> You should submit a comment if you want to:
>
> - Request **clarification** from the author;
> - Leave **constructive criticism** that guides the author in improving the post;
> - Add relevant but **minor or transient** information to a post (e.g. a link to a related question, or an alert to the author that the question has been updated).

There are now 107 deleted comments for that post; your comment is far from alone; another deleted comment, with 662 comment votes, was:

> What's ridiculous about this awesome answer is that it only took you 16 minutes to figure it out.

which also doesn't really ask for clarification or helps to improve the post.

Being in awe with someone's expertise is fine, but can best be expressed by upvoting the answer. If everyone commented like this, we'd have almost 7k deleted comments on that post by now.

Comment: How can I view the history or deletion of a comment?

Comment: @schmunk: you can't, only moderators can see deleted comments.